# Make mark in ctable non italic

Tags: italic, ctable

Ctable prints the footnote marks in italic font, like in the following example.

How would it be possible to print them in a regular font (both in the table and in the footnote section)?

```
\ctable[
caption = {Test},
]{ p{0.39\textwidth} X X X}{
  \tnote[1]{Source}
}{
 & Heading1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3\\
 abcd\tmark[1] &  &\\       
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `\tnote` and `\tmark` macros by adding this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter

% Redefining \tnote
\renewcommand{\tnote}[2][a]{%
   \ifx\@CTnotespar\@CTtrue%
     \@CTtextsuperscript{\normalfont#1}\,#2
   \else%
     \hbox{\@CTtextsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}&#2\NN
   \fi
}

% Redefining \tmark
\renewcommand{\tmark}[1][a]{%
   \hbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}}

\makeatother
```

The original version contains `\textit{#1}` instead of `#1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
\tnote[\normalfont1]
```

and

```
\tmark[\normalfont1]
```